# Speed Issue with sqlite and core data on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview, core-data

I have 40,000+ records in an sqlite db table and am using core data to model the data.

when deployed to a device (iPhone 3G) the data is very slow to load (it takes 5 seconds for the data to load into the tableview). I was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to improve this. I've heard about indexing the data, but am not sure how this is done.

thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you profiled the code to find out exactly where the slow down is?

Comment: no, I haven't. I'll have to find out out to do that. Is that done with Instruments or Shark maybe? thanks.

Comment: That's a very general question and it's impossible for us to know what's happening with info given. However, that said, have you looked at prefectching? Info at: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html

Comment: Are all 40k+ records to be visable in the tableview?

Comment: Shark is a good place to start.  Also consider whether there might be an issue with just displaying any 40,000 row table view by replacing the core data based source with a hard coded source.

Comment: the 40K records are broken up into 70+ categories, the most any tableview would show is 2000 records. the categories are in a plist which then points to the sqlite db using NSFetchedResultsController. I was wondering if I was making a rookie mistake which you wouldn't notice with a small data set but would when handling 1000's of records.

Comment: And how are you loading the NSManagedObjects into memory? Are you using a NSPredicate to search. Ensure if you are that it returns just the correct number of NSManagedObjects into memory. Also look at the prefetching link I mentioned above. This will help prevent the unnecessary loading of managed objects into memory (if done right you can delay loading them until the user actually scrolls to the correct row in the table).

Comment: Yes, I'm using NSPredicate to search. I'll look into prefetching. I read somewhere that:  "If it takes 5 seconds to fetch 21,500 rows, it sounds like you're running on an older device. Like a 3G or original iPhone. The memory and I/O performance on those is just plain slow." I'm using a 3G to test.

Comment: I just added setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching and there's definitely an increase in speed. what was taking 5-6 seconds to load is now taking 2-3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...the 40K records are broken up into 70+
>   categories, the most any tableview
>   would show is 2000 records. the
>   categories are in a plist which then
>   points to the sqlite db using
>   NSFetchedResultsController.

That sounds like a bottleneck. Firstly, the categories have to all be loaded into memory at once as the plist is read in. Depending on how big the category objects/data are, that could eat quite a bit of memory.

More importantly though, it suggest your data model is not well configured. There should be no need for any significant data external to Core Data model. The category data should be part of the data model. If you are using a lot of external data to configure the fetched results controller, then you probably end up with complex, slow predicates for the fetch request. That will bog everything down.

Well configured, Core Data can handle very large and complex data sets without any apparent effort because the data is read only in smallish chunks.

Comment: Also, don't forget about enabling batched fetching, which would only cause small portions of the database to be loaded into memory at any given time.  Use `-setFetchBatchSize:` on your NSFetchRequest for this.